# Defining a random distribution that gives "an integer in the region of x"

Tags: number-theory, probability-distributions

In an informal sense, I think one can reasonably say "an integer randomly selected in the region of $x$ has a probability of approximately $\frac{1}{\ln(x)}$ of being prime".

I'd like to find a way to make that more formal: to find a definition of "an integer randomly selected in the region of $x$" that would make the above statement (approximately) true, that can be implemented algorithmically, and ideally that lends itself to mathematical treatment.

For this to work it clearly requires that integers closer to $x$ should have a higher probability. I suspect that for $z \in \mathbb{R^+}$, the integers $\lceil \frac{z}{x} \rceil$ and $\lfloor \frac{x}{z} \rfloor$ should be picked with roughly equal probability. I'm not sure if it requires that all integers in $\mathbb{Z^+}$ can be picked with some probability: life is clearly going to be easier if it can be bounded. I'm not worried if a definition fails to give good results for very small $x$.

I'd welcome suggestions for what type of distribution might be appropriate, or an explanation why no such distribution can exist.

Motivation: I frequently find myself wanting to answer (approximately) a variety of questions about an integer $n$ randomly selected in the region of $x$, such as:

- what is the probability that $n$ is of form $p^4 q^2 r$;
- what is the probability that $n$ is of form $p^2 q$, given that it is not divisible by 2, 3 or 7;
- what is the probability that $n$ is of form $p^2 q$, given $n \equiv 7 \pmod{12}$;
- what is the probability that $n$ and $n+1$ both have 12 divisors.

I am not aware of any existing theory that answers these types of questions, and I know that I do not have the skill and knowledge to develop such a theory ab initio; however given a definition of "integer in the region of $x$" for which I can write a program, I could get a bunch of statistics that might well give hints of underlying structure.

Comment: For most purposes, you can get away with a very crude definition of "random integer near $x$":  just choose a uniformly random integer in the interval $[1, x]$.  (See [natural density](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Natural_density).)  The reason is that the resulting probabilities typically involve functions like $1/\ln(x)$ (as in your example), which grows so slowly that $1/\ln(x/100)$ and $1/\ln(100x)$ are practically indistinguishable when $x$ is large.

Comment: (Slight correction:  of course I meant that $\ln x$ grows slowly, so its reciprocal shrinks slowly.)

Comment: Thanks, but this doesn't feel like it would give results representative of "near x" unless I do it a second time for another x and take differences, at which point it is testing a uniform distribution on [x_1, x_2]. That doesn't feel like it has the right characteristics, but maybe I should try it anyway - it is certainly easy to implement.